# select2 not displaying in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

Following the instructions here:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/select2-rails/3.1.0/frames

I still cannot get the *select2* displays to show in my simple Rails app. I've made sure the gem installed, added `//= require select2` to `application.js`, and added `*= require select2` to `application.css`. Further, I've included the following in a `users.js.coffee`:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#user_position_ids').select2
```

I have a *User* model that has many *Positions*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
                  :first_name, :last_name, :position_ids

  has_many :positions
  has_one :current_position, :class_name => "Position", 
          :conditions => { :is_current => true }
end
```

I am trying to get the select2 to show on a `collection_select` on my `users/index.html.erb` page:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:position_ids, Position.order(:industry), :id, 
         :industry, {include_blank:true}, {multiple:true}) %>
<% end %>
```

Hence the `$('#user_position_ids').select2` line in my javascripts. Just can't get *select2* to display for some reason so would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran the same issue. After adding the brackets to my coffeescript it worked properly.

So, in your case:

user.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#user_position_ids').select2()
```

or with some options:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#user_position_ids').select2({
        placeholder: "Tags...",
        width: "element",

    })
```